# Android Listview highlight selected rows

Tags: android, listview

I am getting some strange behavior from list view. I need to change background color of rows which confirmed the requirement below but it applied on one or two other rows too. which disappeared on scroll.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (item.get("how_out").equals("not out")) {
         v.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

             return v;
                        }
          }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to the recycling property of the listview. The ListView recycles its textviews onScroll. Hence you need to store the **states** of the textviews using a **boolean array** and handle the textviews inside onScroll listener of the Listview.